# vim color schemes not working after installing with `brew`

Tags: vim, homebrew

I had my vim set up with a number of colorschemes and plugins with the default `vim` install that comes with MacOS. However I needed a version of `vim` with python3 so I installed one via `brew install vim`.

Now the color schemes are not working, and everything is a dark grey color (I'm guessing the default palette for terminal).

Attempts at fixes:

- I've tried running `:PluginInstall` to install the plugins again but nothing changes.
- `syntax on` also does not change anything.

### Updates

Output of `--startuptime`

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.007  000.007: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.088  000.081: Allocated generic buffers
000.592  000.504: locale set
000.596  000.004: clipboard setup
000.601  000.005: window checked
001.208  000.607: inits 1
001.220  000.012: parsing arguments
001.221  000.001: expanding arguments
004.441  003.220: shell init
004.873  000.432: Termcap init
004.891  000.018: inits 2
005.029  000.138: init highlight
005.853  000.087  000.087: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftoff.vim
006.426  000.282  000.282: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
006.900  000.239  000.239: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
018.668  000.029  000.029: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/csv.vim/ftdetect/csv.vim
018.942  000.022  000.022: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/ftdetect/markdown.vim
019.251  008.828  008.777: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
019.772  000.090  000.090: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin.vim
024.535  003.505  003.505: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/colors/lists/default.vim
024.920  004.279  000.774: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
025.203  004.850  000.571: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
025.349  005.291  000.441: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
027.927  002.198  002.198: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/colors/lists/default.vim
029.047  000.240  000.240: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
038.527  010.210  009.970: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim/colors/embark.vim
038.601  033.153  005.928: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
038.611  000.429: sourcing vimrc file(s)
039.437  000.252  000.252: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/csv.vim/plugin/csv.vim
040.265  000.174  000.174: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
041.704  000.881  000.881: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
042.094  000.026  000.026: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/formatter/short_path.vim
044.113  000.254  000.254: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
044.243  004.577  003.242: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
044.545  000.054  000.054: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline-themes/plugin/airline-themes.vim
046.375  000.166  000.166: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/events.vim
046.598  001.663  001.497: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/ale/plugin/ale.vim
047.008  000.137  000.137: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/black/plugin/black.vim
047.339  000.115  000.115: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/plugin/fern.vim
047.622  000.059  000.059: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern-git-status.vim/plugin/fern_git_status.vim
048.860  000.085  000.085: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
049.231  000.260  000.260: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
049.640  000.297  000.297: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
049.800  000.039  000.039: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
050.155  000.247  000.247: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
050.830  000.556  000.556: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
050.984  000.021  000.021: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
051.148  000.042  000.042: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
051.457  000.191  000.191: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
051.734  000.157  000.157: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
052.074  000.194  000.194: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
052.453  000.237  000.237: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
052.498  004.704: loading plugins
052.775  000.277: loading packages
053.940  000.647  000.647: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/indentLine/after/plugin/indentLine.vim
054.148  000.726: loading after plugins
054.156  000.008: inits 3
054.672  000.516: reading viminfo
054.703  000.031: setting raw mode
054.714  000.011: start termcap
054.745  000.031: clearing screen
055.676  000.603  000.603: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
056.024  000.079  000.079: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
056.508  000.288  000.288: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
056.907  000.065  000.065: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
057.578  000.124  000.124: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
058.287  000.375  000.375: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
058.817  001.641  001.142: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
059.264  000.067  000.067: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/csv.vim
059.841  000.152  000.152: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ale.vim
060.384  000.187  000.187: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
060.804  000.095  000.095: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
061.311  000.163  000.163: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
061.738  000.047  000.047: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
062.383  000.067  000.067: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/searchcount.vim
074.981  000.093  000.093: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
075.345  000.704  000.611: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline-themes/autoload/airline/themes/bubblegum.vim
085.582  000.452  000.452: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline-themes/autoload/airline/themes/bubblegum.vim
115.616  000.214  000.214: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
116.310  000.115  000.115: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
154.893  000.354  000.354: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale.vim
155.927  095.889: opening buffers
156.006  000.079: BufEnter autocommands
156.009  000.003: editing files in windows
157.205  000.501  000.501: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/vital/fern.vim
157.722  000.163  000.163: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/vital/_fern/Async/CancellationToken.vim
158.015  000.042  000.042: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/vital/_fern.vim
158.390  001.915  001.209: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern-git-status.vim/autoload/fern_git_status.vim
159.427  000.442  000.442: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/vital/_fern/Async/Promise.vim
160.116  000.153  000.153: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/vital/_fern/Async/Later.vim
160.347  001.705  001.110: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/fern.vim/autoload/fern/hook.vim
165.328  005.699: VimEnter autocommands
165.331  000.003: before starting main loop
168.580  000.543  000.543: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/engine.vim
168.954  000.112  000.112: sourcing /Users/quinoah/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/statusline.vim
171.398  005.412: first screen update
171.400  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
 ~                                                                                                                                                                  ✔  base Py
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you'll need to investigate what is going on exactly. First, make sure that the `vim` you are executing in the terminal is coming from `brew`. You can do that with `which`:

```
$ which vim
/opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

If the path doesn't point to homebrew, then your `$PATH` might need updating. In short: make sure you are using the `vim` executable you installed with `brew`.

Next, check again if the `vim` executable you are running does in fact have support for Python 3 (since you stated that is a need):

```
$ vim --version | grep python3
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
```

Continue to starting up with extra information as to what is being sourced. You do that by running `vim --startuptime vim.log`, then exiting the file and looking at the resulting `vim.log` file. Here is a snippet of what mine looks like:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.004  000.004: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.069  000.065: Allocated generic buffers
001.546  001.477: locale set
001.550  000.004: clipboard setup
...
007.567  000.146: init highlight
008.327  000.248  000.248: sourcing /Users/alfredo/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

In that file, I can see that color schemes are getting sourced and loaded. Check for that in your output. For example, I have `colorscheme tomorrow-night` in my `.vimrc` and I see it in the log output:

```
076.290  025.426  025.186: sourcing /Users/alfredo/.vim/colors/tomorrow-night.vim
```

As you can see, I have my colors in `~/.vim/colors`.

If all of that fails, try using a separate `.vimrc` to run with `vim` so that you check if anything in there is causing problems. You can use a separate one with the `-u` flag: `vim -u empty-vimrc test.txt`. In this case `empty-vimrc` must be a file that exists and has some configuration in it.

Comment: I followed your suggestions (see the output of `--startuptime` in my question). I have isolated the problem to the line in my `.vimrc` "colorscheme embark". Commenting this out generates a "vanila" vim. But obviously I would like to be able to use color schemes, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: you need to have a `~/.vim/colors/` directory with the color files you want. For example `~/.vim/colors/embark.vim` should exist.